# Concept of ViewModel/Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC + WCF applicaiton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, validation

I have the following architecture of my application:
http://clip2net.com/clip/m50879/1303228845-clip-15kb.png

The Model contains a set of POCO objects which should be validated on the web and the services sides. 
Also, I have additional ViewModel layer which is being used only on the web side. The ViewModel layer contains the most of validation logic which is the same as the Model validation logic...

The question is:
What is the best approach to avoid copy-paste of the Model validation logic to the ViewModel validation logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is of interest:
"How to: Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(VS.100).aspx

Comment: From my point of view, the Data Annotation Validators + Custom Metadata Provider is the best solution. :)

But, maybe someone has already faced with the described problem and knows better approach.